# xarray - select/index DataArray from the time labels from another DataArray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have two DataArray objects, called "`A`" and "`B`".

Besides `Latitude` and `Longitude`, both of them have a `time` dimension denoting daily data. `A` has a smaller time coordinates than `B`.

A's time dimension:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 1422)>
array(['2015-03-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-06-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-06-16T00:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-08-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-09-02T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-03-30 2015-06-14 ... 2019-09-02
```

B's time dimension:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 16802)>
array(['1972-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1972-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1972-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', ..., '2017-12-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-12-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-01-01 1972-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
```

Obviously, the A's `time` dimension is a subset of B's `time` dimension. I would like to select data from B using the all the `time` labels from A. As the time in A is not continuous I don't think `slice` is suitable. So I tried using `sel`.

```
B_sel = B.sel(time=A.time)
```

I received an error: `KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, the A's time dimension is a subset of B's time dimension.
>
> I received an error: KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time'"

The error message is suggestive in itself that the assumption made in statement one is wrong. Also, if you look at your time values carefully `A` has values until 2019 whereas `B` ends in 2017.

So, there are 2 ways to solve this:

1. If you're sure that A has all the values in B up till 2017 then

   ```
   sel_dates = A.time.values[A.time.dt.year < 2017]
   B_sel = B.sel(time=sel_dates)
   ```
2. If you're not sure about the values in A being continuous because of some unexpected values in somewhere then you can perform an element-wise check using `np.isin()` which is one of the speed-optimised `numpy` functions

   ```
   sel_dates = A.time.values[np.isin(A.time.values, B.time.values)]

    ## example ##
    ## dates1 is an array of daily dates of 1 month
    dates1 = np.arange('2005-02', '2005-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')
    dates2 = np.array(['2005-02-03', '2002-02-05', '2000-01-05'], dtype='datetime64')
    # checking for dates2 which are a part of dates 1
    print(np.isin(dates2, dates1))
    >>array([ True, False, False])
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
A_new = A.where(A.time.isin(B.time), drop=True)
```

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html

Comment: In this case I think each line of readable and clear explanation, directly here, in English prose, might get you an upvote..... ;-)